# C# equivalent for CreateIoCompletionPort

Tags: c#, winapi

Is there any equivalent for CreateIoCompletionPort in C# (net standard)? Without using PInvoke or something like that,

```
WINBASEAPI
_Ret_maybenull_
HANDLE
WINAPI
CreateIoCompletionPort(
    _In_ HANDLE FileHandle,
    _In_opt_ HANDLE ExistingCompletionPort,
    _In_ ULONG_PTR CompletionKey,
    _In_ DWORD NumberOfConcurrentThreads
    );
```

Comment: E.g., [WebSocket.BeginRead](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebSockets/WebSocketHttpListenerDuplexStream.cs,329) -> [HttpRequestStreamAsyncResult](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_ListenerRequestStream.cs,381) -> [Overlapped](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/overlapped.cs,298) -> [Pack()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/overlapped.cs,381). Most of BeginRead / EndRead etc. use IoCompletion Ports.

Comment: Or [Threadpool.Bindhandle](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/threading/threadpool.cs,1888), specific to the Threadpool functionality.

Comment: `CreateIoCompletionPort` not related to any language. this is windows api function